# Plotting CSV data using myplotlib and pandas in python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, graph

This is what I currently have, I need to plot time on the x and turbidity on the y. Before I can plot the volts from a csv file need to go into the equation Turbidity = (0.07642 * volts) + (-15.122)) and then graphed. I am also getting a date error, I will post the columns below. Here are the columns below, how can I get it to overlook the logger time and the loggerID? I just need the date time on x and the raw sensor converted to turbidity on the y.

```
Date/Time (UTC) Logger Time (unix timestamp)    Raw Sensor (mV) LoggerID
6/27/2018 18:45 1530125111  4.61    Mill Creek B
7/3/2018 18:30  1530642609  92.14   Mill Creek B
7/3/2018 18:45  1530643509  92.03   Mill Creek B
7/3/2018 20:00  1530648013  91.24   Mill Creek B
```

...

```
  import pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime
    import csv
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    headers = ['Raw Sensor','Date','Time']
    df = pd.read_csv('turbiditydata.csv',names=headers)
    print (df)

    df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%d/%m/%y %H:%M'))
    x = df['Date']
    y = df['Turbidity']


    plt.plot(x,y)

    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.title('Turbidity Over Time')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: `...how can I get it to overlook the logger time and the loggerID?` - is that your question?

Comment: All i need is to plot the date/time on the x axis and then the turbdiity on the y. Also how to i take the datafram for volts and convert it to turbidity with the equation i gave.

Comment: Do you have to use Pandas? Are you using the DataFrame for anything else?

Comment: No i dont have to use pandas and no. From the csv file i would just like to plot the date/time on x and then turbidity on the y once it is plugged into the formula, i think im supposed to multiply the data frame but i dont know how.

Comment: `... i think im supposed to multiply the data frame but i dont know how.` - have you spent any time with the [Pandas documentation and tutorials](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) - they are excellant.

Comment: Before I do that the main problem is that I want the graph to show up as it currently does not.

Comment: @user6824158 Can you provide a few lines from the raw turbiditydata.csv file?